# How to run sonarqube on NetBSD

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

According to the requirements document for sonarqube:

> The only prerequisite for running SonarQube is to have Java (Oracle JRE 7 onwards or OpenJDK 7 onwards) installed on your machine.

I want now to use a NetBSD 7.0 machine to run a sonarqube server.
OpenJDK8 is installed:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_77-internal"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_77-internal-pkgsrc_1.8.77-b00)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b00, mixed mode)

However, sonarqube is using *wrapper*, and that software does not support NetBSD (FreeBSD is supported, but this is not close enough to serve as a working substitute).

I already tried using linux emulation mode. But, having a NetBSD native java being started from a linux emulated wrapper is not giving a usable configuration for runtime environment (libc version clashes, et. al.).

And installing a linux native openjdk8 and get the complete setup running in emulation mode is also not to be recommended.

With sonarqube 4.x (long ago) I had used war distribution 
and this worked OK. But with this new environment I hoped for being able to use newer versions of sonarqube.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to bypass wrapper and start sonarqube relying on java only?
2. Alternatively, is there a way to get a NetBSD version of wrapper?
3. Would I be better of dropping sonarqube alltogether,
   given my target platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Java Service Wrapper used by SonarQube does not support NetBSD. That's not as critical as for MSWindows. SonarQube can be easily started as a unix daemon without it. You just have to execute `java -jar lib/sonar-application-{version}.jar` from the installation directory.